# Fatal Error While Setting Border of Button in UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I created a button inside a UITableViewCell. The cell has a .swift class `SampleCell` attached to it. Here is part of the code:

```
class SampleCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    //...
    //other stuff
    //...

}
```

And I wish to add border to this button from another class. Here's what I did:

```
class SampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let sampleCell : SampleCell = SampleCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var identifier : String = "Brightness"
        let identifier_1 : String = "Color"

        if index path.row == 0 {
            identifier = identifier_1

            sampleCell.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
            sampleCell.button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        }
        //other stuff..

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}
```

When I ran the application, I got this error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

at the line `sampleCell.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor`

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating your cells independently? Your cells should be created inside your table view controller delegates. Search for a basic tutorial of how to create a table view controller with custom cells.

Comment: @GurtejSingh cuz I need many different cells that have different UI elements and do different things in a single tableview.

Comment: Well that's not the correct way to do it. Look at EridB's answer below and take it from there. Cells are reused and not independently created in your table view controller delegates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

You are not loading any cell, you are just initializing the class. This means you are not loading the cell's view, therefore the button is nil. The button it is not optional, and unwrapping it will crash your app.

### Solution

Use [UITableViewDatasource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/) `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where you dequeue your cell like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sampleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("your Cell ID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SampleCell
 
    //Your config
    sampleCell.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    sampleCell.button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
 
    return sampleCell
}
```

Comment: sorry I only show part of the code in SampleTableViewController class. I did dequeue cells in latter part of this class

Comment: @AlexLing You won't have that problem if you do your customizations inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I did what you said but still got the same error. I've edited the `SampleTableViewController` class in the question to show what I did.

Comment: oh never mind, I misunderstood what you mean. I think you are right, thanks :)

Comment: Please check and let me know if I can help you further. If that's not the case, then it would good if you mark this answer as accepted but clicking the checkMark on the left side :)